# Find duplicate lines

Tags: python, sorting, uniq

considering this file:
cat 1.txt

```
1 Red
1 Red
2 Red
2 Green
2 Green
4 Blu
5 Black
5 Black
5 Yellow
5 Pink
11 Brown
15 Brown
16 White
```

and this command
  cat file.txt | sort | uniq -c

how could I do the same thing with python?

Comment: import os; os.system("cat file.txt | sort | uniq -c")

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: Lolx!  Great answer, Scott :-)

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Please post that as an answer so I can downvote it so hard. Answering questions that show no research or respect for our time only encourages more VLQ questions.

Comment: @TemporalWolf When Davide submits that as an answer to their instructor, they won't get a good grade.  What I put in the comment is clearly not what their instructor wanted.  My answer aligns with your point.

Comment: OP has asked three questions like this and received answers each time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
from collections import Counter
cnt = Counter()
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        cnt[line] += 1
for k, v in cnt.iteritems():
    print v, k
```

Comment: `with open('file.txt') as infile: cnt = collections.Counter(line.strip() for line in infile)`

Comment: With python3 :
AttributeError: 'Counter' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: @Davide because `iteritems()` is python 2. You should change to `items()`. Also, it is helpful to add a python version tag to questions to avoid this - add the generic `python` flag and then pick one of the `2.7` or `3.x` tags.

Comment: @roganjosh I will do it ;-)